# footer text in tableview is not showing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a basic grouped table view where i have implemented the two methods for setting header and footer for each section. Now, the header text is showing and working just fine. But the text in the footer view is not showing. I have 3 sections and only want to add text to the first footer section. The code:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if ( section == 0 ) {
    return @"Lorem ipsum";
}
return nil;
```

}

Now the weird thing is that it seems that the table is actually making space for the text, it's just not showing. I think there might be some really simple explanation to this, but can't seem to find it:)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are having `heightForFooterInSection` method in your `viewController`. If you are returning any value here, it is the problem. If you are doing, change your code like

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   if (section == 0) {
      return 30.0f;
   }
   return 0.0f;
}
```